# Is raceway wiring allowed in a bathroom?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom

I need to re-wire my bathroom (I live in Oregon, USA), and for various reasons, it would be much easier to install raceway than to try and get everything wired through the walls/ceiling. Is raceway wiring in a bathroom allowed?

The raceway would only be about 10' length total, running from a double wall switch about 6' up to the ceiling and then down to a light and then another 3' over to a through-the-wall exhaust fan.

The electrical outlet will be GFCI, 20amp, on a totally different circuit running inside the wall. So that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the NEC that *prohibits* the installation of surface raceway (metal or nonmetallic) in even a damp or a wet location provided the conductors inside are rated for said damp or wet location.

That said, many AHJs do not consider the area outside of the shower zone to be a damp location to begin with.  So, go ahead with the raceway -- just remember to use a wire (such as THWN) suitable for a damp or wet location when running wires inside the raceway.

Comment: I think 388.12 does have a specific restriction that form damp and wet locations.

Comment: @batsplatsterson -- I'm looking at the 2014 NEC 388.12 and not seeing it...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that surface raceway is OK for dry locations (NEC 386.10 / 388.10), but not damp or wet locations (NEC 386.12 /388.12).  In the bathroom, you couldn't run it in the shower / tub area.

There is a rule that lights within three feet of the shower / tub area have to be rated for damp locations, and if they're subject to shower spray, they have to be rated for wet locations.

edit:  at ThreePhase's direction I see that the restriction in 386.12 / 388.12 is no longer there.  A little googling and it looks like it was not in the 2002 code, then was in there for a couple cycles, now it's out again.

To be safe - I'd only use it where it's explicitly permitted.

Comment: Are areas more than 3 feet horizontally from shower/tub considered to be dry? All of the raceway would be at least 4 feet horizontally from the shower/tub. There would be occasional steam, of course, but I'd think the raceway would keep out any condensation.

Comment: I believe beyond the 3 foot zone it's considered a dry location.  You might want to use THWN instead of THHN anyway.

Comment: ***NEC 2014 410.10 (D) Bathtub and Shower Areas.** No parts of cord-connected luminaires, chain-, cable-, or cord-suspended luminaires, lighting track, pendants, or ceiling-suspended (paddle) fans shall be located within a zone measured 900 mm (3 ft) horizontally and 2.5 m (8 ft) vertically from the top of the bathtub rim or shower stall threshold. This zone is all encompassing and includes the space directly over the tub or shower stall...* Nothing about fixtures being damp rated in this zone.

Comment: Reading further... ***NEC 2014 410.10(D) Bathtub and Shower Areas.** ... Luminaires located within the actual outside dimension of the bathtub or shower to a height of 2.5 m (8 ft) vertically from the top of the bathtub rim or shower threshold shall be marked for damp locations, or marked for wet locations where subject to shower spray.* So fixtures only have to be damp/wet rated it they are above the tub/shower.

Comment: And receptacles and switches are allowed in that zone...

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like beyond that 3ft (and maybe even within it, depending on shower spray issues) is not considered to be a wet or damp location. So raceway should be allowed. As suggested, I may use THWN just to play it safe. Of course, electrical inspector will have the final say, but I'm just making plans in advance. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the raceway. PVC is used in dairy barns for wash down so it would not be a problem anywhere in your bathroom. Surface metal (or nonmetallic) raceway is only for dry locations. Just about all wire now is slash rated THHN/THWN so you get both ratings in one wire.

Comment: @batsplatsterson No mention of the additional 3' zone, when talking about switches or receptacles.  ***404.4(C) Switches in Tub or Shower Spaces.** Switches shall not be installed within tubs or shower spaces unless installed as part of a listed tub or shower assembly.* ***"406.9(C) Bathtub and Shower Space.** Receptacles shall not be installed within or directly over a bathtub or shower stall.*